# Unable to load app using Express and NightmareJS

Tags: express, nightmare

I'm developing a little app with Express-Generator files structure and NightmareJS, so i'm using routes. The Nightmare function is in my index.js file inside the routes directory, the wait() function inside Nightmare is setting up at 8000 so it waits eight seconds until the right element loads. Everything looks fine but when I run the app it can't find the index file and shows the 404 Not Found page but if I wait eight seconds and refresh the page then it works.
I made another test without routes, I mean, working only in the app.js file and it works fine, the page waits for the loading time and then shows the results, so that makes me think that I'm configuring something wrong in the routes files? Any ideas? Thank you.

This is my code:

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var allday = require('./routes/allday');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('view options', {layout:false});

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/allday', allday);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare();
var url = 'http://portus.puertos.es/Portus_RT/table.html?&t=1&p=MjA1NjA4Mjs7LTIuMzMyOTk5OTQ0Njg2ODg5Njs7MzYuODMzMDAwMTgzMTA1NDc7O1dBTkE7OzA7OzIwNTYwODI7O1dBTkFfREFUQTs7OztNRURJVEVSUkFORU87OzA7OzEyOztNRUQ=&locale=es'

nightmare
  .goto(url)
  .wait(8000)
  .evaluate(function () {
    var currentData = [];
    var dayData = [];
    var dir_waves = '';
    var checker = '';
    var size = '.gwt-TabPanelBottom>div>table>tbody>tr>td:nth-of-type(2)>table>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(10)>td:nth-of-type';
    var period = '.gwt-TabPanelBottom>div>table>tbody>tr>td:nth-of-type(2)>table>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(12)>td:nth-of-type';
    var direction = '.gwt-TabPanelBottom>div>table>tbody>tr>td:nth-of-type(2)>table>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(11)>td:nth-of-type';
    var wind = '.gwt-TabPanelBottom>div>table>tbody>tr>td:nth-of-type(2)>table>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(2)>td:nth-of-type';
    var time = '.gwt-TabPanelBottom>div>table>tbody>tr>td:nth-of-type(2)>table>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(1)>td:nth-of-type';

    for(var i = 7; i <= 21; i++) {
      var size_waves = document.querySelector(size + '(' + i + ')').innerText;
      var period_waves = document.querySelector(period + '(' + i + ')').innerText;
      var direction_waves = document.querySelector(direction + '(' + i + ')' + '>div').title;
      var wind_vel = document.querySelector(wind + '(' + i + ')').innerText;
      var hour = document.querySelector(time + '(' + i + ')').innerText;

      //Preparing data to show

      //Asking just numbers for degrees
      direction_waves = direction_waves.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');

      // Translating numbers into coordinates
      if (direction_waves == 0) {
        dir_waves = 'N';
      } else if(direction_waves > 0 || direction_waves < 90){
        dir_waves = 'NE';
      } else if(direction_waves == 90){
        dir_waves = 'E';
      } else if(direction_waves > 90 || direction_waves < 180){
        dir_waves = 'SE';
      } else if(direction_waves == 180){
        dir_waves = 'S';
      } else if(direction_waves > 180 || direction_waves < 270){
        dir_waves = 'SO';
      } else if(direction_waves == 270){
        dir_waves = 'O';
      } else if(direction_waves > 270 || direction_waves < 360){
        dir_waves = 'NO';
      } else {
        dir_waves = 'N';
      }

      //All day data
      dayData.push([hour, size_waves, period_waves, direction_waves, dir_waves, wind_vel]);

      //Checking current hour for data
      Date.prototype.timeNow = function () {
        return ((this.getHours() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getHours();
      }
      var dateTime = new Date().timeNow();

      //Current time data
      if (dateTime == hour) {
        currentData.push([hour, size_waves, period_waves, direction_waves, dir_waves, wind_vel]);
      }

      //Surf checking
      if (currentData[1] > 0.6 && currentData[2] >= 6 && currentData[3] <= 200 && currentData[5] <= 5) {
        checker = ["SURF'S UP!", "thumbs-up"];
      } else {
        checker = ["SURF'S DOWN", "thumbs-down"];
      }
    }
    return [dayData, currentData, checker];

  })
  .end()
  .then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
      res.render('index', {data: result});
    });
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Search failed:', error);
  });

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Relevant code to reproduce might help to know better. Please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think problem lies in line 29-34. The one with comment: 
// catch 404 and forward to error handler.
It runs every time not only in case of exceptions.
As per [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html), "The function is executed every time the app receives a request."
Even if you plan to use it call next(null) in successful cases, and next(err) only in case of actual errors. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you devilpreet, but I'm sorry, still have no idea about fixing the problem, I'm newbie programming in general. I'm thinking about adding a setTimeout function to the error handler so it have to wait 8s until it looks for the error or something like that. Have no clues.

Comment: I get it. I would suggest you to build up from (Basic) [https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html] and then build up gradually. You might need deeper understanding of javascript and node.js as well.

Comment: Thanks for your advice devilpreet, I'll try it. By the way, the link is broken.